# Border outline on first letter

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, outline

**How to outline the bottom border of a first letter?** In the example below, `p:first-letter`, all I get is the red underline. Can't even score the first-letter outline (Outline = Block Elements)! Is there some other way to code an outline for the bottom border of a `:first-letter`?

I tried CSS combinatory tricks, etc. without success. I feel certain that a pseudo attribute and/or pseudo element of some sort would display for browser DOM whatever the Word application programmers are displaying in documents when a cursor touches a word and outlines the bottom border under the first letter of that touched word (this attractive programming artifact or feature does not print. The linked sample is font Impact, font-size 36 in Wordpad.exe. Outlined border under the small "t".

**Expected Output:**

[image: Outline on the bottom border of the first letter]

```css
p:first-letter {border-bottom: 1px solid red;font-size: 48px;}
p:first-letter*=["border-bottom"] {outline: green solid thin;}
```

```html
<p><span class="spec">Note...</span> Outline properties work best if !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
```

CSS3 has the property `border-image`. Add `border-left: 0;` etc., or `border-image: url(border.png) 0 0 30 0 stretch;` and you can see that border-image can display only on the bottom (not inline, for block elements).

[CSS Tricks - Gradient Borders](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) [pseudo element block knockout]

You can play around for free at the W3 schoolhouse, where some css3 properties are supported for border image. Failing all else, fuss up a drop-cap arrangement, but the span is there in the example for a reason: we want image-border property's outline inline. This means adapting ["knock out"?] DOM's HTML behavior with element and/or attribute selectors. Any ideas?

**References**

- [CSS Tricks - Outline](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/)
- [W3Schools - Try It Border Image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image)
- "CSS3 Visual Quickstart Guide", Jason Cranford Teague, chapter 6 Text Properties, page 167.

Comment: What do you mean by outlining a border? Your image shows just a line below “t”, and it can be set using underlining, border, or outline, depending on the desired distance.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: My guess was that OP was probably looking to get that double line effect (of-course can still be done with border itself) with an hollow area in between. But yeah it is better for the OP themselves to clarify it.

Answer (score 6):

To make the **ouline on the first-letter** pseudo element, you can use box-shadows.
I commented the *CSS* code so you can see what each line of the `box-shadow` property does:

```css
p:first-letter {font-size: 48px;
  box-shadow: 
    0 3px 0 -1px #fff, /* to indent the green bottom line with the same color as the background */
    0 3px 0 0 green,  /* to create a bottom 3px high green line */
    inset 0 -1px 0 0 green; /* to create the top (1px) of the outline */
}
```

```html
<p><span class="spec">Note...</span> Outline properties work best if !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
<p><span class="spec">Info.</span> Outline properties work best if !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
```

Comment: This is the better answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The below is an option using a `pseudo-element` to generate an outline (similar to your PNG image) for the first letter.

The tricky part with this method is that the `pseudo-element`'s width need to be set according to the width of the first letter and if not the outline would be wider/narrower than the first letter. In order to get this sorted, I have added a `data-first-letter` attribute to the `p` tag and have set this as the `content` of the `pseudo-element` and have given it the same `font-size` as the `p:first-letter`. You have to somehow key in the correct value for this attribute for every such paragraph (either manually or using JS).

```css
p:first-letter {
  font-size: 48px;
}
p {
  position: relative;
}
p:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em; /* setting in em to make positioning change in accordance with font-size */
  left: 0px; /* if you have a padding left on the paragraph then this should have an equivalent offset */
  content: attr(data-first-letter); /* to make the width of the outline same as first letter */
  font-size: 48px; /* same as first letter */
  width: auto;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden; /* to make sure the content is not displayed */
  outline: 1px solid green; /* or border: 1px solid green; */
}

/* to demonstrate the changes when padding left is used */

.withpadding{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.withpadding:after{
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p data-first-letter='N'>
  <span class="spec">Note...</span> Outline properties work best if !DOCTYPE is specified.
</p>

<p data-first-letter='I'>
  <span class="spec">Info...</span> Outline properties work best if !DOCTYPE is specified.
</p>

<p data-first-letter='I' class="withpadding">
  <span class="spec">Info...</span> Outline properties work best if !DOCTYPE is specified.
</p>
```

---

Finally, some additional points to note:

1. The selector `p:first-letter*=["border-bottom"]` in the sample provided in question is wrong. CSS has only attribute selectors and you cannot verify whether the element has bottom border or not like that (which I assume was your intention).
2. [`first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) pseudo-element does not support `outline` property as specified in the linked MDN page and hence it cannot be put to use.